# Make an entire row a table clickable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, d3.js

I have a table with multiple columns and rows. I want to be able to click on any `<tr>` and it open a page in a new/same tab.

I don't want to add my `<td>` text/value inside an `<a>` because then there will be some parts of a tr that will not accept clicks to open the link..my cursor would have to hover over some text.

I have seen solutions to do this with jquery ( https://electrictoolbox.com/jquey-make-entire-table-row-clickable/  ).

How can I do this with just plain vanilla JS? How can I do this with just using D3.js?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl At first I thought I wasn't being clear with my solutions and my current progress on the problem (because of your comment), but another SO user clicked the link and made the connection and answered.  The current solutions that I have tried were listed..with the anchor tags inside every td..but I don't want that. The solution I currently have is exactly copy and paste of that jQuery example in that link I posted (otherwise a "minimal" reproducible example). I didn't really want to post walls of text as I don't prefer reading them, I felt it was redundant with the link already.

Comment: Answers should be self contained. We shouldn't have to go off site to review your issue. If you click on `<>` in question editor you can even make a runnable demo right here in the page

Comment: @charlietfl Ah ok. Must be a new feature..I haven't posted in a while. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just use click o doubleClick event

1. on load event for verify document is ready to attach events click on elements
2. just get table and children (tr)
3. use forEach (iterate) to attach even click or dbclick tr.onclick = yourfunction

check this example taking a base table of you link and adding my custom js

```js
// attach event onLoad (onready wih jQuery)
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onLoad);
window.addEventListener("load", onLoad);

function onLoad() {
  const table = document.getElementById("example")
  clickableRows(table, onClickRow)
}

/*
Event onClick Row
*/
function onClickRow(mouseEvent) {

  const clickedRow = mouseEvent.target.tagName = "TD" ? mouseEvent.target.parentElement : mouseEvent.target;
  console.log(mouseEvent, clickedRow);
  alert("click on cell with text << " + mouseEvent.target.innerText + " >>");
}
/*
Add click event each row (TR tags)
*/
function clickableRows(tableElement, clickEvent) {
  if (!tableElement || (tableElement && tableElement.tagName !== 'TABLE')) return;
  const rows = tableElement.querySelectorAll("tr");
  rows.forEach(row => {
    // override onclick event, all TR will use same function on trigger event click
    // row.onclick = clickEvent;
    // maybe u want double click instead click    
    row.ondblclick = clickEvent;
  })
}
```

```css
table#example {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
}

#example tr {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
}

#example tr:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#example th {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#example th,
#example td {
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

#example td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table id="example">
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="apples">Edit</a></td>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Blah blah blah blah</td>
    <td>10.23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="bananas">Edit</a></td>
    <td>Bananas</td>
    <td>Blah blah blah blah</td>
    <td>11.45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="oranges">Edit</a></td>
    <td>Oranges</td>
    <td>Blah blah blah blah</td>
    <td>12.56</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```